# Assuming that only the 2nd order terms are zero

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I am dealing with first-order perturbative theory, that is, any variable may be decomposed as

$a = a + \delta a$

and the same would occur with several different variables, let's say, $b$ and $c$. However any term that is accompanied by a $\delta$ (i.e. $\delta a$, $\delta b$ and $\delta c$) are called "perturbative terms", that is, any $\delta$-term multiplied by any other term with $\delta$ are zero (using a different lingo: just keeping perturbation to the first order):

$\delta a ^2 =0$;

and

$\delta b \delta c = 0$.

In my case these terms are used in several different calculations throughout my program, so I would like to discriminate these conditions as a global assumption (actually any other idea on how to do this would be gladly accepted) in the beginning of the program. So I have tried something like:

```
$Assumptions = $\delta a^2 == 0$ && $\delta b \delta c == 0$
```

and henceforth for every different combination of variables.

Obviously, it does not work out. I have tried several different ways to do it and, in the end of my big calculations, I just to simplify equations using `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`, get results in which second order perturbative terms do not appear.

Edit:

In my case, the perturbative terms are dependent of two different variables:

$\delta a = \delta a (t,r)$.

So it is really common to appear derivative terms multiplying between the $\delta$-terms, in which must be set to zero. Examples of this would be:

$\partial_r \delta a \partial_r \delta b = 0$,
or
$\partial_t \delta a \partial_r \delta a = 0$,
or
$(\partial_t \delta c)^2 = 0$.

How should I add rules to take care of these derivative terms?

Comment: You can introduce scaling of the variables, for instance $a=a_0+\alpha x$,  $b=b_0+\beta x$, and  $c=c_0+\gamma x$. Next you do your calculations and at the end perform series expansion with respect to $x$ and keep only terms up to the 1st order in $x$, that is `Series[f[x],{x,0,1}]//Normal`.

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce the perturbative part as `δ[a]` and define an extra rule how multiplication works with those (δ can be entered quickly via <kbd>Esc</kbd>delta<kbd>Esc</kbd> or via `\[Delta]`):

```
δ /: Times[___, _δ, _δ, ___] = 0;
```

Now every time at least two `δ[_]` symbols are multiplied they will be simplified to zero automatically. For example in

```
(* Input *)
(a + δ[a]) (b + δ[b])
% // Expand

(* Output *)
(a + δ[a]) (b + δ[b])
a b + b δ[a] + a δ[b]
```

after expanding the expression, the `δ[a]δ[b]` part was replaced by zero automatically.

We have to be a bit careful because this rule doesn't catch powers of `δ[_]` so we should add another rule for that:

```
δ /: Power[_δ, n_Integer?(# >= 2 &)] = 0;
```

Now we can for example do

```
(* Input *)
Table[δ[a]^k, {k, 0, 3}]

(* Output *)
{1, δ[a], 0, 0}
```

I'm not sure what should happen for negative powers with absolute value of at least two, but you can modify/add another rule similarly to the two above.

Comment: Probably safer to use `UpValues` rather than to redefine something as fundamental as `Times`: `\[Delta] /: Times[_\[Delta], _\[Delta]] = 0;`.

Comment: @march Great idea! i'll update my answer to use `UpValues` instead.

Comment: I suppose that `δ /: Times[___, _δ,___, _δ, ___] = 0;` is good to make sure that it always works. However, since `Times` is `Orderless`, I'm pretty sure the pattern matcher will just check to see if there are two `\[delta][_]'s` that are multiplied, regardless of whether there are other quantities there or not. I think that `\[Delta]  /: Times[_\[Delta], _\[Delta]] = 0` on it's own should work.

Comment: Ok, great answer. It seems like it is working flawlessly. However, if I may ask, lots of derivative terms also appear like $\partial_r \delta a \partial_r \delta b$ and even with different variables, $\partial_t \delta a \partial_r \delta c$. They also should turn out to be zero (since anything with two $\delta$ must become zero). Any easy way to work around this?

Comment: @march Yes, originally i had the extra `___` in the pattern, when i had the same realisation about the `Orderless` property, after which i removed it. Both patterns should work i guess.

Comment: @EdisonCesar It shoud be possible to add a similar rule to properly transform expressions containing derivatives of deltas. Can you update your question with a simple example expression, where you get derivative terms?

Comment: I edited the question concerning the derivative terms.

Comment: If I take the derivative of any term with $\delta$, I get (by the chain rule):

$\partial_r \delta[a[r]] = a`[r] \delta`b[r]$

which makes total sense , however that is not how I would like it to work.