# Vanishing with the derivative terms in perturbation theory

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Following the question in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206196/assuming-that-only-the-2nd-order-terms-are-zero), now I would like to make the terms with derivatives to vanish. To shortly explain, given a variable decomposed as follows:

$a(t,r) = a(r) + \delta a(t,r)$

in my long calculations several derivatives of the term $\delta a(t,r)$ appears like $\partial_t \delta a(t,r)$ or $\partial_r \delta a(t,r)$. But I need that multiplied $\delta$-terms with another to vanish, like

$\partial_r \delta a(t,r) \partial_r \delta b(t,r)=0$
or
$(\partial_r \delta a(t,r))^2 =0$
or
$\partial_r \delta a(t,r) \partial_t \delta a(t,r)$.

In my previous question, the method showed was able to answer only when there are not derivative terms and I would like to generalize it. If I follow the method showed, Mathematica takes the derivative of the variable $\delta a(t,r)$ as:

```
\partial_r \delta[a[t,r]] = \delta'[a[t,r]] \partial_r a[t,r].
```

following the chain rule. And, obviously, it does not results in zero when two terms of this type are multiplied.

Comment: Multiply all your deltas by some `ϵ`. Set `ϵ /: ϵ^n_ /; n >= 2 = 0;`. Voilà.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform That is what I have suggested in the comment to the original post. I have seen the original accepted solution. I am sure it works, but I have a feeling that simple algebraic approach is more appropriate here. Not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Well, it worked. Thanks a lot. Do you know any way to set $\epsilon = 1$ by the end of the whole set of calculations? My equations are kinda messy and huge, any simplifications, or anything to let me look at them easier, would be greatly appreciated.